# npm list not returning package paths

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ghost-blog

npm has started to seriously under perform recently, I have attempted to re install ghost a number of times but since installing it to its current location npm cant find its path.

I enter the below from /home/usr

```
$ npm list ghost --parseable

$ npm list express --parseable

$
```

and again in /node_modules I then get the below.

```
pi@raspberrypi://home/pi/node_modules$ npm list ghost --parseable
npm WARN package.json has-binary-data@0.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json socket.io-adapter@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json debug@0.6.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json bind@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json emitter@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json indexof@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json object-component@0.0.3 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json parseuri@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json parsejson@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json parseqs@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json better-assert@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json callsite@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Am I right in thinking npm has lost the path to the above package.json files?

Comment: npm install ghost has given me the following... npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: ghost@0.4.2
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"~0.10.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"1.2.25","node":"v0.11.3"}

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.20+
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "ghost"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.25
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: What command line did you use to install ghost or express?

Comment: I had that problem when npm hasn't enough permissions (for example using the `-g` option without sudo). After trying it I'll suggest an update `sudo npm update npm -g`.

Comment: I'm sure I installed Node and npm globally, I had to revert back to a slightly older npm install as the most resent one would give an error when requesting npm -v "invalid, identifier" or something along those lines. So after searching for the right combination that worked on the pi, I will try and re install npm and node. From what I have read there seems to be a concern raised by many that using sudo npm can be quite detrimental to npm's performance I believe this was the main difference when I installed express, installing it -g.